# Can I modify a for...of loop's variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-of-loop

If I do

```
for (let x of arr)
{
  x = x * x;
}
```

how could I make the changes made to `x` change in the original `arr`?
I tried the above but `arr` doesn't change.

Comment: `x` is just a local variable scoped to one iteration of the loop. Of course reassigning it doesn’t affect `arr` in any way.

Comment: Can I use `.map()`?

Comment: Of course. That’s what the linked question suggests.